# Akka.NET Cluster Sharding - Control shard rebalancing to stop the entity only when it reaches a specific state

Tags: akka.net, akka-cluster

In Akka.NET cluster sharding I have an entity that can spawn between two behavior states (Idle, Processing). When the entity is in the processing state I don't want the rebalancing mechanism to stop the entity. How can I control shard rebalancing to stop the entity only when it reaches the "Idle" state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Akka.net - How to wait child actor to process all pending messages prior to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285419/akka-net-how-to-wait-child-actor-to-process-all-pending-messages-prior-to-stop)

Comment: I saw this article that you wrote  a few years ago:
https://petabridge.com/blog/cluster-sharding-technical-overview-akkadotnet/

"When a rebalancing is going to occur a shard will send a hand off message to all of it’s entities. By default this message will be a PoisonPill causing them all to stop immediately but you can replace it with a custom one in case if you need to perform some preparations before migrating."

How exactly can I change the default rebalance "PoisonPill" message to a custom one?

Comment: My answer from the link to another SO question above covers that: `ClusterSharding.Start` method overload can take custom `handOffMessage` parameter used as a replacement for PoisonPill.